# A function $y(x)$ satisfies the differential equation $y^{\prime}=4\sqrt{y-x^2}$ It is known that $y(1)=2$. Find $y(3)$.

Tags: contest-math

A function $y(x)$ satisfies the differential equation 
$$y^{\prime}=4\sqrt{y-x^2}$$

It is known that $y(1)=2$. Find $y(3)$.

My attempt: Clearly $y^{\prime}=4$ at $x=1$. That's all(LOL). Any hint to proceed will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but $y\colon x\mapsto 2x^2$ seems to be a solution (found by eyeballing). And trying to apply Cauchy-Lipschitz/Picard–Lindelöf  may show it's the only one.

Comment: @ClementC. Nice "solution by inspection"! I spent some time trying to manipulate it into a familiar form and couldn't get there.

Answer (score 3):

For amusement, let us solve the ODE/IVP for the case $y(1) > 2$ the hard way
and then discover the solution for the case $y(1) = 2$ as some sort of a limit.

Let $z = \sqrt{y-x^2}$, we have $y = x^2 + z^2$ and

$$y' = 4\sqrt{y-x^2} \iff (x^2+z^2)' = 4z \iff zz' + x  = 2z \iff z' = 2 - \frac{x}{z}$$
Let $u = \frac{x}{z} \iff z  = \frac{z}{u}$. We will temporarily assume $y(1) > 2$ so that $z > 1$ and $u < 1$. Under such an assumption, the last expression is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{u} - \frac{xu'}{u^2} = 2 - u
\iff xu' = u^2( u - 2 + \frac{1}{u}) = u(u-1)^2$$
This leads to
$$\begin{align}\frac{dx}{x} 
&= \frac{du}{u(u-1)^2} = \left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u}\right)\frac{du}{u-1}
= \left(\frac{1}{(u-1)^2} - \frac{1}{u-1} + \frac{1}{u}\right)du\\
&= d\left[\log\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right) + \frac{u}{1-u}\right]
\end{align}$$
This implies
$$\frac{u}{1-u}\exp\left(\frac{u}{1-u}\right) = Kx
\iff \frac{u}{1-u} = W(Kx) 
\iff u = \frac{W(Kx)}{1+W(Kx)}$$
for some suitable chosen constant $K$ and $W(x)$ is the 
[Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
As a result, if $y(1) > 2$, we have

$$z = \frac{x}{u} = x \left(\frac{1}{W(Kx)} + 1\right)
\implies
 y = x^2 + z^2 = x^2\left[1  + \left(\frac{1}{W(Kx)} + 1\right)^2\right]$$
Substituting the boundary condition at $x = 1$, we have

$$K = W^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(1)-1}-1}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y(1)-1}-1} \exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(1)-1}-1}\right)$$

When we reduce $y(1)$ to $2^{+}$, $K \to +\infty$, for any $x > 0$, $\frac{1}{W(Kx)} \to 0$. This suggests in the limit $y(1) = 2$, we have

$$y \stackrel{?}{=} x^2 \left(1 + (0 + 1)^2\right) = 2x^2$$

Substitute this back into the original ODE $y' = 4\sqrt{y - x^2}$, $y = 2x^2$ is indeed a solution of it.
So $y(3) = 2\times 3^2 = 18$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the solution of $y^{\prime}=4\sqrt{y-x^2}$ with condition $y(1)=2$ is :
$$y(x)=2x^2$$
I let find $y(3)$.

What is more interresting (but outside the scope of the question) is how to solve the ODE for the general solution:

[image]

Note : the case $C=0$ corresponds to the particular solution $y=2x^2$ . The parametric form is not valid in this case because $F=2$ , meanwhile the implicit equation which is reduced to $\sqrt{y-x^2}-x=0$ continues to be valid.